# Joining tables with merge rules in ArcGIS

Tags: arcmap, attribute-joins

I have two tables in ArcGIS that contain a mutual unique identifier, which the join will be based upon. However, table2 has multiple records of the unique identifier. There is another field in table2 which represents a "tally" of some value. I want to create the join between table1 and table2 so that the largest (max) value in the "tally" field is joined in the operation. How can I do this inside of ArcMap (preferably), or excel/python if not.

Table1

```
ObjectID | UID
       0 |  72
       1 |  89
       2 |  99
```

Table2

```
ObjectID | UID | Tally
       0 |  72 |     0
       1 |  72 |     1
       2 |  72 |     2
       3 |  72 |     3
       4 |  89 |     0
       5 |  89 |     1
       6 |  89 |     2
       7 |  99 |     0
       8 |  99 |     1
       9 |  99 |     2
      10 |  99 |     3
      11 |  99 |     4
```

TableJoin

```
ObjectID | UID | Tally
       0 |  72 |     3
       1 |  89 |     2
       2 |  99 |     4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Table2 is spatial you can use the [Dissolve](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000005n000000) tool.  Set UID as the Dissolve Field, and add a Statistic Field for Tally with Type set to Max.

If Table2 is not spatial and just a normal table, use the [Summary Statistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001z000000.htm) tool.  Set UID as the case field, and add a MAX statistic field for your tally.

Comment: This is correct, I was returning to answer my own question at this point. The Table2 is not spatial and therefore a summary statistics is calculated. This output is then joined to Table1 to produce TableJoin. I was infact searching for the equivalent of the Dissolve tool for non-spatial tables.